# insert image in a line wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, kinect

I'm working in an application that draw runtime some lines (it is a kinect application, the lines that it draw are the player skeleton). This is the code for drawing a line :

```
var line = new Line
{
     StrokeThickness = thickness,
     X1 = seg.X1,
     Y1 = seg.Y1,
     X2 = seg.X2,
     Y2 = seg.Y2,
     Stroke = this.bonesBrush,
     StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
     StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round
};

children.Add(line);
```

it works but i have to add an image over this line, how i can do in code behind for wpf and c#? If this shape not support image i can use a rettangle also or an ellipse...

Comment: maybe the is more correct to say that i have to fill this line with an image

Comment: You may use an `ImageBrush` for your `bonesBrush` field.